# Version Table Data Cleanup

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE audit_table (
    id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    auditversion int4 NOT NULL,
    value jsonb NOT NULL,
    delta text[] NULL,
    src text NOT NULL,
    usr text NOT NULL,
    meta hstore NULL,
    last_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT audit_table PRIMARY KEY (id,auditversion)
);
```

auditversion column is auto incremented for every unique id. Version is incremented for the same id. For new Id it starts from 1.

I am planning to write one clean up query. The requirements are like this

1. Keep the latest 30 versions
2. do not remove the record if the record is last updated in after certain day 2020-08-01. So there is a chance that after 2020-08-01 we can more more than 30 versioned items.

This is what I have so far:

```
delete from audit_table pa
using (select id,  MAX(a.auditversion) as maxVersion 
       FROM audit_table a group by id) pm 
where pm.id = pa.id
  and pa.auditversion <= (pm.maxVersion-30)
  and pa.last_updated < '2020-08-01';
```

Let me know if this can be written in better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks good to me.

An alternative approach you could consider is adding a trigger `ON INSERT OR UPDATE` that purges old entries for `NEW.id` on every data modification. That is probably more total effort, but avoids a single long running `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Thank you. This table is updated more frequently. So, having trigger might slow down the system for regular operations. This delete will be scheduled during low load hours.